# Prove that a complex function is continuous over its domain

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

**Question:** Prove that the function $f(z):=\dfrac{\bar{z}+i}{z-i} +z^2$ is continuous over the domain $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{i\}$.

**Attempts:** Showing that the function is differentiable is the way I'd normally do it, however this question is intended to be done without proving differentiability, and I'm not sure how to formally prove it and set out that proof. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a sum/product/quotient of the continuous functions $z$ and $\bar z$

Comment: Are you allowed to use continuity of the arithmetic operations and conjugation ?